# Cannot do positional indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have a time series dataframe "his" with datetime index out of which I want to extract a certain range of timesteps. The starting point "selected_var_start" is in datetime index format (extracted from another dataframe). I want to extract in total 24 h.

I try do it like this: `his = his.iloc[selected_var_start:(selected_var_start+pd.DateOffset(hours=24))]`

I get the following error `TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers [DatetimeIndex(['2010-11-12 19:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Datetime', freq=None)] of type DatetimeIndex`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is for "*purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position*" - use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) instead.

Comment: If I use `his = his.loc[selected_var_start:(selected_var_start+pd.DateOffset(hours=24))]` I get "pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: DatetimeIndex(['2010-11-12 19:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Datetime', freq=None)"

Comment: that's just general advice; if you need a detailed answer, please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the first element of `selected_var_start`. Try this `selected_var_start[0]`. This will transform you element from `DatetimeIndex` to simply `Timestamp`, which works with loc.

```
his.loc[selected_var_start[0]:(selected_var_start[0]+pd.DateOffset(hours=24))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `loc` with strings

```
pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('11/01/2010', '12/01/2010')).loc['2010-11-12': '2010-11-13']
```

Comment: Can I include the time somehow? I guess I would have to use  selected_var_start.strftime(dateformat) but i looks like I can use only date but not time during the day?